# How to handle multiple services with different timeouts/policies in dotnet

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

HttpClient documentation states that a single HttpClient should be reused throughout the application lifetime to avoid resource exhaustion, but in newer dotnet versions, HttpClientFactory is a way to create short-lived clients (that will notice DNS changes), sort of contradicting the previous pattern if I understand well

Still, I have doubts on what is the right way to achieve the following:

- I have calls to make to services for which I know the URL in advance (so I could have a typed client representing them, for instance)
- I have calls to make to URLs I will obtain at runtime from parsing some responses, so I can't create compile-time typed clients
- I want to be able to configure different timeouts, retry policies, credentials for the different URIs I will call

What approach should I then take? If I go with a single HttpClient, I am not sure how I can have the configurability of the 3rd bulletpoint (nor if it will properly manage connections across various services), and if I use the multiple short-lived clients approach, I wonder how I can efficiently apply the different configurations (as it things to add a lot of object creation overhead) and it seems I may use reusability of clients registered at application startup with 'AddHttpClient'

Comment: I don't know if this is the best approach, but what I ended up doing is relying on typed clients when I know the configuration in advance, and relying on a generic named client that I create various instances of with HttpClientFactory for the various runtime URLs I get. That way, I can still leverage all the handlers configured at application startup

Answer (score 0):

You can check my sample first, hope it can help you.

[image]

*Program.cs*

```
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServiceA", client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.bing.com");
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        });//.AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicyA());

        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServiceB", client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://ASDASQWEQWte.DAS.com/");
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        });//.AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicyB());

        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServiceC", client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://QWE.ADSA.com/en-us/");
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        });//.AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicyC());
```

*MyhttpClientFactoryService.cs*

```
using NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types;

namespace TeseSample
{
    public class MyhttpClientFactoryService
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
        private HttpClient _httpClient;
        public MyhttpClientFactoryService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }
        public HttpClient CreateHttpClient(string serviceName)
        {
            _httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(serviceName);

            return _httpClient;

        }
    }
}
```

*MyController.cs*

```
using Azure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace TestSample.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IEmployeeRepository _repository;
        public MyhttpClientFactoryService _myservice;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
        private HttpClient _httpClient;
        public EmployeeController(IEmployeeRepository repository, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
            _httpClient = httpClient;
            _myservice = new MyhttpClientFactoryService(_httpClientFactory, _httpClient);
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetEmployees()
        {
            return Ok(_repository.GetAllEmployees());
        }
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CallServiceAAsync()
        {
            Dictionary<int,string> result = new Dictionary<int,string>();
            var clientA = _myservice.CreateHttpClient("ServiceA");
            var clientB = _myservice.CreateHttpClient("ServiceB");
            var clientC = _myservice.CreateHttpClient("ServiceC");

            try
            {
                var responseA = await clientA.GetAsync("/ttranslatev3?isVertical=1&&IG=286C376174344D0990E1B200C0D37201&IID=translator.5026");
                result.Add(200, "success :" +responseA.RequestMessage.RequestUri.Host);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.Add(500, ex.Message);
                //throw;
            }
            
            try
            {
                var responseB = await clientB.GetAsync("/ttranslatev3?isVertical=1&&IG=286C376174344D0990E1B200C0D37201&IID=translator.5026");
                result.Add(201, "success :" + responseB.RequestMessage.RequestUri.Host);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.Add(501, ex.Message );
                //throw;
            }

            try
            {
                var responseC = await clientC.GetAsync("/ttranslatev3?isVertical=1&&IG=286C376174344D0990E1B200C0D37201&IID=translator.5026");
                result.Add(200, "success :" + responseC.RequestMessage.RequestUri.Host);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.Add(502, ex.Message);
                
                //throw;
            }
            return Ok(result);
        }
    }
}
```